# Set the default font in Emacs daemon on OSX

Tags: macos, emacs, fonts

I'd like to change the default font in Cocoa Emacs on OSX.

I know that in X11 emacs, one can just configure the defaults in an XResources file and they will apply to all frames. In Windows, it's possible to use registry settings to do the same thing. However, I couldn't find a way of doing that on OSX. Is it possible?

I'd rather keep my font settings outside of lisp if possible.

Comment: Please include both the lisp line you used and the error you received. We can't read your mind.

Comment: In addition to the example below by @lawlist, here is the link to the official documentation that provides an example of how to set font using the `default-frame-alist`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html

Comment: @terdon: In the question, I indicated that I was looking for an alternative to XResources/Registry that works on OSX with the Cocoa version of Emacs.

Comment: Editing the `.emacs` file should work in all cases. Including the error you get can help us understand why it's not working.